# How much is the probability of $\cos x \cos(4-x)<0$ for $0<x<4$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have this function
$$f(x)=g(x)h(x)=\cos x \cos(4-x)$$
How much is the probability of $f(x)<0$ for $0<x<4$?

Comment: You mean $x$ is chosen uniformly over the interval?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel YES

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the answer assumes that $x$ is chosen **uniformly** over $[0,4]$.

$$\cos x\cos (4-x) > 0$$ for $$x\in \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, 4-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
on $[0,4]$.

So the probability you require is $$1 - \frac{4-\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}\approx 0.785$$

For reference, here is the graph on $[0,4]$ -

[image]

Comment: Nope! The function you mention is always positive. In fact after a little simplification you'll see that it is $\sin ^2(\frac{3x}{2})$. The required probability is thus, zero.

Comment: @ strawberry-sunshine Thank you very much.